# change clickonce install path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I deployed a project via ClickOnce cause I like the update features, but after install on some systems its hard to find.

```
On windows Vista and Windows 7, you will find the ClickOnce cache here: c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\obfuscatedfoldername\obfuscatedfoldername

On Windows XP, you will find it here: C:\Documents and Settings\username\LocalSettings\Apps\2.0\obfuscatedfoldername\obfuscatedfoldername
```

Is it possible to change the path of an application installed via ClickOnce? I've looked in the publish settings and don't see a way to change the default path.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's beyond the scope of a ClickOnce install.

Why don't you distribute your updates through the ClickOnce system?

Comment: I'd like to set the default install path.  I am using the ClickOnce system.

Comment: Again, like I said, that's not to you to decide. If you update your app through clickonce you don't have to care about where it is installed.